# Right way to dispose of a WWW IEnumerator after it has completed - Unity

Tags: unity, web, memory

What is the "right" way to dispose of an Ienumerator coroutine after it has completed?

Comment: If you're using WWW, you're looking at very old samples. You should use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html

Answer (score 1):

Do nothing.

You let the IEnumerator method run to the end and then let the garbage collector take care of it automatically.

C# is a garbage-collected language. There are very few edge cases where you need to dispose things manually, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: Well, when you do rendertexture or texture read/write you should dispose of the texture - so i wonder if ienumerators are also required to be manually disposed of?

Comment: @ina No, coroutines do not need to be disposed in Unity. Render textures are one of the few edge-cases I mentioned above where a manual release is required.